# How do I configure a CentOS 7 VLAN interface with bridge to KVM

Tags: networking, virtualization, centos-7, linux-kvm, vlan

I wanted to set up my CentOS 7 server so that my KVM Virtual Machines pull a DHCP lease from my Cisco Meraki MX (firewall) configured VLAN 30 and are segregated from VLAN 1.

As I do not have two physical interfaces, I figured I would virtualize one, add the VLAN tag to it, and then bridge the virtualized, VLAN tagged, interface and set that in my virt-install script. However I wanted to ensure that all traffic running to my CentOS box itself remained on VLAN 1 (with the exception of traffic headed to the VMs).

I thought I had it working the other day, however on a whim I attempted to ping across subnets and was surprised to see ICMP responses.

I (sort of) followed this reference in setting everything up: [Setting Up 802.1Q VLAN Tagging Using ifcfg Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configure_802_1q_vlan_tagging_using_the_command_line)

Currently I have `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1` (default ethernet interface) configured as follows:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
GATEWAY="192.168.128.1"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="em1"
UUID="bac1228e-fe29-4e7c-9073-6b2d4542d003"
DEVICE="em1"
ONBOOT="yes"
ZONE=public
```

This interface does successfully pull a 192.168.128.x IP from the VLAN 1 subnet.

Next I have `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1.30` (virtual interface with VLAN 30 tag):

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
#BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEVICE="em1.30"
ONBOOT="yes"
ZONE=public
VLAN="yes"
BRIDGE="br0"
```

Which due to the BRIDGE option (I believe) does not pull an IP address.

Finally, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0` (my bridged connection from em1.30):

```
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
IPV6INIT="no"
DEFROUTE="no"
GATEWAY="10.100.0.1"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Bridge"
DELAY="0"
ZONE=public
```

This interface also pulls the correct DHCP route from the VLAN 30 subnet (10.100.0.x)

Using the br0 interface in my virt-install scripts appears to work as all my VMs when launched do successfully pull from the VLAN 30 subnet as well.
However, as mentioned above, when I try and ping (or SSH) from one subnet to the other, I get full responses.

I suspect that this has something to do with the routes perhaps? Here is the output of `route -n`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.128.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
10.100.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1045   0        0 br0
192.168.128.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
```

For what it's worth, `/etc/sysconfig/network` is currently blank, I have disabled NetworkManager, and when I thought it was working, I had no DEFROUTE or GATEWAY option set in ifcfg-br0 (I added those today with no change in result so I left them).

Do I perhaps need a VLAN option set in ifcfg-br0 as well as ifcfg-em1.30?
Thanks for taking the time to read all of that!

Comment: [ServerFault similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/841177/how-do-i-pass-vlan-traffic-over-a-bridge-to-kvm-vms)

Recommendation here is to create two separate virtual interfaces off off the physical ethernet interface. So perhaps creating em1.1 as well as em1.30, THEN bridging em1.30?

I will try this soon and report back for anyone who is interested.